# What is ${PYTHON_REL} FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, python, environment-variables

I have an error whilst making a port, so I checked the makefile, and found the problematic line.

The issue is that I don't know how to fix it, as I don't know how to change the Python_Rel variable.

Where is this located and how do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined in an include-file read by the make program, e.g., by this line at the end of the port makefile:

```
.include <bsd.port.mk>
```

On my FreeBSD 10 system, the include-files are in `/usr/ports/Mk`, and `grep` finds these matches:

```
$ fgrep -n PYTHON_REL *
bsd.python.mk:70:# PYTHON_REL           - Version number in numerical format, to ease
bsd.python.mk:353:PYTHON_REL=           341
bsd.python.mk:364:PYTHON_REL=           335
bsd.python.mk:375:PYTHON_REL=           325
bsd.python.mk:386:PYTHON_REL=           278
bsd.python.mk:394:PYTHON_REL!=          ${PYTHON_CMD} -c 'import sys; h = "%x" % sys.hexversion; \
bsd.python.mk:505:      defined(PYTHON_REL)
bsd.python.mk:553:.if ${PYTHON_REL} >= 320 && defined(PYTHON_PY3K_PLIST_HACK)
bsd.python.mk:569:.endif # ${PYTHON_REL} >= 320 && defined(PYTHON_PY3K_PLIST_HACK)
```

and `bsd.python.mk` is included conditionally (`grep` is your friend):

```
$ fgrep -n bsd.python.mk *
bsd.port.mk:398:#                                 Implies inclusion of bsd.python.mk. (Also see
bsd.port.mk:1446:.include "${PORTSDIR}/Mk/bsd.python.mk"
bsd.port.mk:1893:.include "${PORTSDIR}/Mk/bsd.python.mk"
bsd.python.mk:4:# $FreeBSD: head/Mk/bsd.python.mk 362364 2014-07-20 19:47:45Z antoine $
bsd.python.mk:9:Python_Pre_Include=             bsd.python.mk
bsd.python.mk:630:Python_Post_Include=                  bsd.python.mk
bsd.wx.mk:11:# variables (e.g. USE_PYTHON) are defined before it (this is a bsd.python.mk
```

and the comment in that file says

```
# USE_PYTHON    - If set, this port relies on the Python language. 
#                                 Implies inclusion of bsd.python.mk. (Also see 
#                                 that file for more information on USE_PYTHON_*
#                                 and USE_PYDISTUTILS).
```

and it *uses* the setting like this:

```
.if defined(USE_PYTHON) || defined(USE_PYTHON_BUILD) || defined(USE_PYTHON_RUN) 
.include "${PORTSDIR}/Mk/bsd.python.mk"
.endif
```

So the short answer is that your port makefile is missing one of the settings needed to include the file which defined `PYTHON_REL`, e.g.,

```
USE_PYTHON = yes
```

There's a nice `README` file at the top of the ports tree, showing where detailed information can be found.

In working with ports, you might want to keep track of changes made.  For instance, [`bsd.python.mk`](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/branches/2014Q1/Mk/bsd.python.mk?view=log) was updated later, according to the [FreeBSD ports-wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Python):

Split bsd.python.mk into a USES for consumer ports and an port-tree specific .mk file ([20140809: Commit r364450](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports?view=revision&revision=364450))

and the `PYTHON_REL` variable appears to have been regarded as obsolete, since it was no longer defined after that commit (see [file](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/Mk/Uses/python.mk?view=markup&pathrev=364450)).

If it's important to your port, you could construct that variable with something like

```
PYTHON_REL = ${PYTHON3_DEFAULT:S/.//}
```

Comment: I ran fgrep -n PYTHON_REL * ; in the /usr/ports/Mk/ directory, but it returned nothing. Additionally, an ls of the directory does not reveal any bsd.python.mk

Comment: is that in the makefile? How would I set it to use /usr/local/bin/python 2.7 ?

Comment: There's a `PYTHON2_DEFAULT` symbol as well.  You could investigate how it is set in your copy of the ports, and set `PYTHON_REL` using that.